# How do I build a basic C# program in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've looked all over the internet and stackoverflow for guides, but VS Code is seeming very bare bones. I tried making a simple Hello World program, but the IDE is complaining about things like tasks.json and launch.json (which it helpfully generated for me... to some extent), but I have no idea what values to put in for anything in there. It also asked for project.json, which it did not generate, so I made one up (and weirdly it doesn't go under .vscode with the other files?). I have no idea what settings to put in that project.json and all the documentation I find about it is very generic. I also had to make a project.lock.json for some reason, whatever that is.

Is there a tutorial somewhere on how to use this? I just want to make the world's simplest basic console C# program. The only guides I could find were targetted at ASP.NET which I don't care about.

The project.json I cobbled together:

```
{
  "version": "0.1-alpha-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "code": ["**/*.cs"],
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": {}
  }
}
```

Do I use "mono" instead of "dotnet"? Where is the doc for that?

My launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug ConsoleApplication",
            "type": "coreclr", // or "mono"?
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Where does "workspaceRoot" get defined? In project.json? How?

My tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [ ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this okay? Will this work with Linux/mono?

Comment: Well, wrt `tasks.json`, you could put here different calls for different OS (Windows, Linux, OS X), see https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks